# Setting a button image depending on another variable? Swift

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9

so I'm very new to swift. I currently have 16 buttons all set to individual outlets box1,box2,box3 etc.

Each box I have set a tag and what I am trying to do is set the image of a particular box based off another integer variable to determine which box I'm changing.

So say I do a calculation and index = 4.
Is there a way I can then set box(index).setImage?

I understand this probably isn't the best way to do it or even possible, maybe I can set each button to an array of objects instead? Any tips would be great.

Comment: You are looking for `viewWithTag()`.

Comment: you can use IBOutletCollection for that

Comment: When you say boxes... What do you mean?  Are you  trying to change the background image of the button that is pressed?

Comment: Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the image of button through some tag then you don't need any outlets for the buttons.

You can change your button image by finding the button through viewWithTag() property.

Here is the code

```
var button = self.view.viewWithTag(Your_Calculated_Index) as! UIButton
button.setImage(Your_Image, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You need to create an array for the button.

```
@IBOutlet var allbtns: [UIButton]!

for buttons in allbtns{
    if buttons.tag == 4{
        print("Button 4 ");
        buttons.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagname"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }else{
        print("Other buttons except 4 ");
    }
}
```